# email type input : dynamically change color/text of the button if the email is wrong or correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an email type input inside a form where a user can submit his email address to recover his password if this one has been forgotten.

By default, if the user hasn't typed anything inside the input, the button simply displays a grey @ symbol.
I'm looking for a way, once the user starts typing in the input, to change the text/color of the submit button (for instance an orange "X" when the email is incorrect, and a green "check" when it's correct.

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: Handle `onkeyup` event of the input and check input value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it :

```html
<html>
    <title>This is test</title>
    <head>
        <style>
            .btn {
                color:#000;
                -webkit-transition: background 1s linear;
                -moz-transition: background 1s linear;
                -ms-transition: background 1s linear;
                -o-transition: background 1s linear;
                transition: background 1s linear;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        
        Enter Email : <input type="text" class="email">
        <button class="btn">Submit</button>
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>

         $(document).ready(function(){
             
              $(".email").on("input",function(){
                  
                  if ($(this).val() == "")
                      $(".btn").css({backgroundColor:""});
                  
                  else {
                      if (checkEmail($(this).val()))
                          $(".btn").css({backgroundColor:"green"});
                      else
                          $(".btn").css({backgroundColor:"red"});
                  }
              })
              
              function checkEmail(txt) {
                  var patt = /[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,3}$/;
                  if(patt.test(txt))
                      return true;
                  else
                      return false;
              }
         })

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very interesting aswell, 2 quick questions as I'm not very familiar with JS yet, can I a "elseif" like in php to turn the button grey again if the input is emptied by the user ? Also, how can I add "fade" to the function to get a color transition between every states (empty/incorrect/correct) ?

Comment: @apatik , you want background input be gray if it be empty?

Comment: yes indeed, something like "grey if empty" "orange if incorrect but not empty" "green if correct". I believe I can find a way to make a transition with all this using the Fade function of JQuery/JS

Comment: this is perfect, thanks a lot for your help on this ! One last question : where is the transition defined on the script ? (so i can adjust the transition duration) Thanks again !

Comment: transition is in `style` tag. i do it with css.

Answer (score 1):

A simple )

```css
input:not(:valid) {
  background-color: #f60;
  }
```

```html
<input type="email">
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var inputElement = document.getElementById('email');
var buttonElement = document.getElementById('button')

function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}

email.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  if(e.target.value === "") {
    return;
  }
  if(validateEmail(e.target.value)) {
    buttonElement.style['background-color']="green";
  }
  else {
        buttonElement.style['background-color']="red";
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="email" id="email">
<button type="button" id="button">submit</button>
```

As stated in previous answer by Andrey Fedorov, you can use the HTML5 form validation. If you want to perform validation programmatically  you can use the below example

```
var inputElement = document.getElementById('email');
var buttonElement = document.getElementById('button')

//Stolen from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript
function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}

email.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  if(e.target.value === "") {
    return;
  }
  if(validateEmail(e.target.value)) {
    buttonElement.style['background-color']="green";
  }
  else {
        buttonElement.style['background-color']="red";
  }
});
```

Fetch the input element and listen for the `keyup` event. Whenever the event is fired, validate the input and set the color of the button.

jsbin example: http://jsbin.com/xepijemeha/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this looks to be what I was trying to implement, but I'm completly unfamiliar with the keyup event. I'm going to try that out.

Answer (score 0):

Some CSS solution for this would be:

```css
input + button::before {
    content: '+ ';
    color: green;
}
input:invalid + button::before {
    content: 'X ';
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="email" required />
<button>Submit</button>
```